# System Update Downloaded

Tags: updates, nexus-7, android-versions

I have Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.4) and got message:

> System update downloaded 
>   Android 5.0.2 System Update

But when I press on it, nothing happens.

How can I install this update?

**UPDATE:** About Tablet screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Nexus 7 (2012) on 4.4.4.

Do you have multiple user accounts on your tablet? If so, have you tried installing the update from the other account(s)?

I have two accounts, and when the 5.0.2 update got pushed to my device, both accounts got the notification. However, one of them had the same symptoms you described -- nothing happened when I pressed the notification, and the settings app didn't say anything about the update. From the other account, the update worked.

Strangely, the account that worked was not the one I created when I setup the tablet.

Comment: yes, it worked, installed from other account.

Answer (score 0):

On your Nexus tablet go to:

1. All Apps
2. Settings
3. About Tablet
4. System Updates

This should take you to a screen that tells you that you have a system update downloaded, and it should have the option to "Restart and Install".

Comment: I don't have System Updates there

Comment: @Alex, have you done anything weird to the tablet?  Rooted it?  Unlocked it?  etc?  I'm not sure why "System Updates" wouldn't be on that menu.

Comment: no, did nothing

Comment: Sorry if you have, but have you tried restarting the tablet?

Comment: yes, restarted several times

Comment: Can you take a picture of what is under your "about tablet" menu?